# Centering commutative diagram (using diagrams package)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, diagrams

When one has long text in a centered commutative diagram, apparently the diagram is centered as if the long text wasn't there. The result is that the diagram does not appear to be centered. I would like the amount of whitespace on the left to be the same as on the right. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[balance,small,nohug]{diagrams}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{diagram}
 a & b & very long text goes here and it just keeps going.\\
 c & d & e\\
 f & g & h
\end{diagram}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

And a screen shot of the result.[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package code is obfuscated but this probably works

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[balance,small,nohug]{diagrams}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
X\dotfill X

\sbox0{\begin{diagram}
 a & b & very long text goes here and it just keeps going.\\
 c & d & e\\
 f & g & h
\end{diagram}\global\setbox1\lastbox}
\usebox{1}

X\dotfill X
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works well. It looks like you're changing the box which the centering is being applied to, is that correct?

Comment: the environment inserts a fixed `\kern` space before the box (I have no idea how the value is calculated) this just does the env in a box so I can extract the main diagram box, leaving the kern spacing, then just let `center` center that box.

Comment: ok I was also proceeding from the id query and did not pay attention to other posts and I also worked via emacs using "it's all text" firefox plug-in. I will delete comments later.